# Mistakes in Amidah

Tags: shemoneh-esrei

I could not find this answered specifically, so I apologize in advance if this is a duplicate.

If you make a pronunciation mistake, or lose your place in the final section of the amidah, can you go back the the start of a sentence you have not completed? For example, say I lose my place in יהי רצון מלפניך, can I simply restart the sentence from יהי?

I assume you can, since one who says
שלום רב on a fast day and realizes before they complete the blessing is instructed to simply restart at
שים שלום, but wanted to confirm.

If so, can you always restart a section that you have not yet completed?

Comment: Which is the "final section"?

Comment: I meant anything after רצה by “final section” because in the middle blessings I know you can return to the start of sentence you make a mistake and carry on in the correct order.

Answer (score 2):

As correctly noted in the comments, a mistake during the middle brachos, can be corrected by going back to the beginning of that bracha. However, during the first and last 3 brachos a mistake would require going back to the beginning of the set 3 not just back to the bracha you were in middle of.

The [MB 114:34](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Berurah.114.34?lang=bi)

> איזה דבר שאם היה אירע כזה בברכה אחרת היה צריך לחזור לראש אותה ברכה לכך בג' ראשונות ואחרונות חוזר לראש דחשובות כחדא אבל אם טעה באמצע אין מעכב

Just to clarify, the MB says that  a mistake that requires going back means that it was in the end of the Bracha or some other mistake that makes the bracha invalid, but a mistake in middle of the bracha that did not affect the meaning does not require going back

[MB 119:13](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Berurah.119.13?lang=bi)

> וטעה פי' ששינה בה בענין שצריך לחזור מחמת זה ועיין מה שכתבנו לעיל בסימן ס"ח במ"ב סק"א ותרווייהו איירי בשוגג דבמזיד צריך לחזור לתחלת י"ח

The case that you mentioned about יהי לרצון is a little different since it’s not in the middle of a bracha at all.